# azure vhd storage pool space usage

Tags: azure, vhd, sparse-file

I have 4 1TB VHD disks attached to a single VM.
In the VM, I have created a simple fixed storage pool from the 4 = 4TB.
In disk manager I created a single 4TB volume/partition.
The volume is only 30% full.
VHD is sparse so I would expect the underlying VHDs to only use 1.3TB or so, but according to the portal, the 4 VHDs are using 920GB, 920GB, 577GB and 1 GB (=2.4TB) total.
Can this discrepancy be explained?

[image: combined screenshot of various spaces used]

VD size/number of columns etc:
[image]

Comment: I did open an azure support request but it's been a week and no response

Comment: Can you please confirm the column size being used?

Comment: added virtual disk metadata to the question - does that help?

Comment: azure acknowledged that this is an issue and have removed the "used size". I am not sure if billing is affected or not.